# Type of stain...?

Tags: finishing, staining

How does this guy do to get this kind of stain/finish. It is dark in some areas and light in others. This was a small chuck of the show table that I thought would be the most useful. Does anybody know how this is done for such a neat look? (not including the scratching :P)
[image: Wood from my show-table.]

Comment: Isn't this just the [difference of absorption betwen earlywood and latewood](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5HBH2ibu-ZwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MaximeMorin Understand that I do not even understand this whole early-wood and late-wood with one single board. I was just asking how he could have these darker spots and yet light. I can take a picture of the whole thing if it helps all of you. Also the link you have does not work or I have a problem, for when I go to the page it has a error.

Answer (score 5):

First off you should recognise this as softwood and most softwoods have soft (and consequently absorbent) earlywood while the denser latewood is very much the opposite.

Due to these characteristic something like this can be done by two methods, staining or scorching. In both cases the earlywood goes dark while the latewood remains largely unchanged, at worst creating this sort of garish stripy effect where the grain flips or [reverses](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/how-can-i-match-gunstock-oak-with-pine/2805#2805).

I don't know if it's just the photo but the wood also looks quite yellow, which might be due to varnish, either a spar varnish which is more obviously yellow initially or a normal varnish that's been on for a while — all oil-based varnishes age and become more yellow over time. In addition the wood itself 'mellows' with exposure to light and becomes naturally more yellow.

Comment: Yes it does have a yellow tint to it. Very interesting for which I would not know per say how wood can be early and yet late? because it is one piece. But this does help and I thank you kindly sir!

Comment: @Ljk2000 Earlywood and latewood should be explained in any general woodworking book. You've read at least one of those, right? ;-) It's nothing complicated, it just refers to wood the tree grows early in the year (when growth is fast, hence the light bands tend to wider) and later in the year (when growth is slow, hence the narrower dark bands). The terms spring wood and winter wood refer to the same thing.

Comment: Ya sure, I should of know better. I know what you mean know. Was not using my brain at the time. Yes I know about that, growing faster in the summer than winter. And I also know how the wood grown in the winter is harder than in the summer, if I am not mistaken.